World Properties not showing (DAZ TP BLENDER )
I have an issue and I'm stuck. I have installed the Diffeomorphic plugin to export DAZ characters to Blender. The issue occurs when I simply import the character into Blender, then go to the World properties and change the background color there. But instead of changing the background color, the color of the character is changed and the background is transparent. Why is this happening?

Hello and welcome. Please don't write in all caps in the title or body of any posts, it is the written equivalent of shouting, is harder to read and may be considered rude. Please use the [edit] button below the post to change your text into regular case.

You should add a screenshot or render to demonstrate.

I don't think this has anything to do with the model you imported. The world background being "transparent" could be a number of things, the most obvious being that Film -> Transparent is turned on. As for why the character appears to change color, assuming you are actually editing the World material and not the Object material, there's a good chance that this is just the effect of colored lighting hitting your character. I.E., the background may be invisible, but it still effects objects in the scene, and putting them under for example red light makes them look red. It's hard to say without any screenshots, but those are my best guesses.
